# Particle system appear inside UI?

Tags: unity

How to make the particle system appear inside the Canvas ? No need for unity store assets. 
I'm using Unity 5.5.0

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to put a particle system on the UI, but maybe someone can surprise me.

Comment: Can you show us a mock screenshot of the effect you want to achieve? There may be a way to accomplish that effect by positioning a particle system in a particular way in worldspace, or layering multiple cameras, or other solutions that don't involve rendering the particles as UI per se.

Comment: something like this on YT. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8bTLzxYRlw]

Comment: You may trying changing your UI camera to Screen Space - Camera (not Overlay).  I don't know if using multiple cameras would work for this (a 3D camera over top of a 2D UI canvas).

Comment: In UIExtansion exist some functionality.
You can try this: https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Controls/UIParticleSystem

Comment: For anyone looking here in the future: [ParticleEffectForUGUI](https://github.com/mob-sakai/ParticleEffectForUGUI)